# How to Identify Patterns for Print Loops

Tags: java

I am a student and I have a test coming up where I strongly believe that there is going to be at least one question about print loops. I understand the general idea behind them but I have a hard time finding the necessary patterns to solve the problem completely. For example:

[image: Sorry for bad screen shot not sure why that is happening]

to solve this problem I have the following code:

```
    public static void drawTriangle(int width)
{
    for (int r = 1; r <= (width + 1) / 2; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 1; c <= width; c++)
        {
            if (r == 1 || c == r)
            {
                System.out.println("*");
                } else {
                System.out.println("_");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far which is almost correct but I am missing r+c == width + 1. I know that this is the code to form the side of the triangle going up. My problem is that I did not or rather could not recognize that I needed this part in the solution. Is there any tips that anybody has for identifying these patterns?

Comment: Pattern detection is the key to software development, the other half is identification of problems that the existing solutions fit. Either you have it or you don't, but, It can be learned with intense study.

Comment: The instructions say: "Complete the method drawTriangle by filling in the blank with the missing code. Do not change any other part of the method." Can we see the original code with the blanks?...or did you write a solution completely from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

I try this . I think this example will help you somehow.

```
public static void drawTriangle(int width) {
    int rows ;
    if(width % 2 == 0){
        rows = width/2;
    }else{
        rows = (width+1)/2;
    }

    for (int i=rows; i>= 1 ; i--) {
        for (int j = i; j < rows ; j++) {
            System.out.print("_");
        }
        for (int k = 1; k <= (2*i -1) ;k++) {
            if( k==1 || i == rows || k==(2*i-1)) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("_");
            }
        }
        for (int y = rows; y > i ; y--) {
            System.out.print("_");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version:

```
class Main {
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i=1; i<=8; i++) {
      System.out.println(i + ":");
      drawTriangle(i);
      System.out.println();
    }
  }

  public static void drawTriangle(int width) {
    for(int left=0, right=(width-1); left<=right; left++, right--) {
      for(int col=0; col<width; col++) {
        System.out.print((left==0 || col==left || col==right) ? "*" : "-");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
  
}
```

Producing:

```
1:
*

2:
**

3:
***
-*-

4:
****
-**-

5:
*****
-*-*-
--*--

6:
******
-*--*-
--**--

7:
*******
-*---*-
--*-*--
---*---

8:
********
-*----*-
--*--*--
---**---
```